# How to configure my app options in the settings app

Tags: ios, appsettings, settings.bundle

I've added my own Settings.bundle file to my app so that I can display 1 or 2 preferences I'd like to expose to my user. This works fine.

When I click on my app name in the setting app I see a couple of options that I have not explicitly asked for, namely notifications and location services under a title of "ipad settings".

Other apps I have seen have these options in the main notifications and location sections of the settings app, NOT under their own app name.

How can I remove these 2 items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since iOS8 each App have these options in the Main section AND in their own section. To edit you should read the [Apple Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html).

Comment: thats great. Have you a reference I can refer to?